# Calculating Time Granulation

Tags: php, datetime

I have a requirement to achieve the following on a site in PHP.

Our users specify a 'granulation' value in their app - i.e. 14400 which represents 4 hours of time.

Now, basically what I need to do is to track an 'action' based on this granulation from midnight - for example, if an action occurs at 03:15am, it would get tracked under the time 00:00 - 03:59, similarly if an action occurs at 4:25am, it would be tracked under the 04:00 - 07:59.

I'm trying to write a function which has the following:

```
function _get_granulation($granulation)
{
    $time = date("G:i"); // Gives us current time (e.g. 04:15 or 22:10)
    $iterations = ($granulation/86400); // Number of iterations in a 24hr period    
}
```

Now I'm a little bit stuck as to where I go from here.

Esentially, all I need it to do is to pass the time value back representing what timeframe to record the entry for.

Can anyone advise/help from here?

Comment: What do you expect out of the function? The start time of the time segment? The numeric index of which time segment it is in the day (ie. 1-6 for your example of 14400 hours)?

Comment: What is the expectation when daylight savings changes?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to get the timeslot that this action belongs in. So a time value...

Comment: When DST goes back/ahead, it would simply track the additional hour in that timeframe - unless you have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should give you what you're looking for:

```
function _get_granulation($granulation, $now = null) {
    if (is_null($now)) $now = time();
    $daySecs = date('G', $now) * 3600 + date('i', $now) * 60 + date('s', $now);
    $segment = $granulation * floor($daySecs / $granulation);
    $hrs = floor($segment / 3600);
    $min = floor(($segment - $hrs * 3600) / 60);
    $sec = $segment - $hrs * 3600 - $min * 60;
    return date('H:i:s', mktime($hrs, $min, $sec));
}
```

I don't use unix timestamps directly, to avoid daylight savings problems, but instead use the actual hours/minute/second values.

I've added an extra parameters to help test so we don't always have to use the current time. That allows a test script like this:

```
$times = array('10:30:00', '07:59:00', '23:20:00');
$granulations = array(21600, 14400, 3600, 1800);
foreach ($granulations as $g) foreach ($times as $t) {
    $segment = _get_granulation($g, strtotime($t));
    echo("{$t} / {$g} = {$segment}\n");
}
```

Which produces output like this:

```
10:30:00 / 21600 = 06:00:00
07:59:00 / 21600 = 06:00:00
23:20:00 / 21600 = 18:00:00
10:30:00 / 14400 = 08:00:00
07:59:00 / 14400 = 04:00:00
23:20:00 / 14400 = 20:00:00
10:30:00 / 3600 = 10:00:00
07:59:00 / 3600 = 07:00:00
23:20:00 / 3600 = 23:00:00
10:30:00 / 1800 = 10:30:00
07:59:00 / 1800 = 07:30:00
23:20:00 / 1800 = 23:00:00
```